# Converting HTML to PDF renders Arabic text as question marks

Tags: c#, .net, itext, pdf-generation, arabic

I'm using iTextsharp in an Asp.net application. When converting HTML with Arabic text to PDF, the resulting PDF shows question marks.

How can I convert HTML with content in different languages to PDF using iText?

Comment: Please note that asking for a recommendation of another tool or library isn't allowed on Stack Overflow. I removed that part of your question when I corrected your English. You've already received 2 close votes and 1 down-vote, probably because you describe your problem **without providing any source code.** It is impossible for anyone to know which version of iText you are using. Maybe you're using `HTMLWorker` (deprecated; will never work for Arabic) or XML Worker (isn't supported anymore either). You should read the official documentation; see my answer for links to the tutorial and FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

You want to convert HTML with Arabic text to PDF using iText for .NET. In that case, you need [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET), the [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) add-on and the [pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) (*). In your question, you talk about iTextSharp, which leads to believe that you're using an old version of iText. Make sure you have the right version.

In the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml), there's a chapter about fonts: [Using fonts in pdfHTML](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml)

There's an example involving Arabic in the section entitled "Internationalization":

[image]

Your HTML contains Arabic characters, and I assume that the encoding of that HTML file is Unicode. Maybe you're using an old version of iText that reads such files using another encoding by default.

As described in [How to display Arabic strings from RTL in PDF generated using itext 7 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621260/how-to-display-arabic-strings-from-rtl-in-pdf-generated-using-itext-7-api) you need a font that supports the Arabic glyphs. Please show us some code so that we can see which font you are using. Maybe no Arabic characters are shown because you didn't define the correct font.

Take a look at this FAQ entry: [How to convert HTML containing Arabic/Hebrew characters to PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-convert-html-containing-arabichebrew-characters-pdf)

[image]

We need three fonts: one regular for the English text, an Arabic font for the Arabic text, and a Hebrew font for the text in Hebrew:

```
public static final String[] FONTS = {
    "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/NotoSans-Regular.ttf",
    "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf",
    "src/main/resources/fonts/noto/NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf"
};
```

The code to convert the HTML on the left to the PDF on the right in this figure looks like this in Java (the C# code is very similar; only minor changes need to be applied):

```
public void createPdf(String src, String[] fonts, String dest) throws IOException {
    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    for (String font : fonts) {
        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font);
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
    }
    properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest), properties);
}
```

You are also asking for "multiple language" support, but as the FAQ explains: all languages are supported by iText *provided that you have the necessary font files for those languages.* See [Which languages are supported in pdfHTML?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/which-languages-are-supported-pdfhtml)

The Java code for this example looks like this (it shouldn't be a problem for a C# developer to port this code to C#):

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
fontProvider.addDirectory(fonts);
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdf, properties);
```

The directory indicated with `fonts` points at a directory full of NOTO fonts (free fonts provided by Google for an abundance of languages).

(*) **Important note:**

iText and the pdfHTML add-on are available as AGPL software (just like the old iTextSharp version you're probably using). This means that you can use this software for free *on condition that* you also release your software as free software under the AGPL.

Unfortunately, we've noticed that many developers ignored the AGPL license and used iText in a closed source context without purchasing a commercial license. Sometimes, developers did this out of ignorance. To avoid ignorance, we've decided to make the pdfCalligraph add-on (the add-on you need for support for Arabic, Hebrew, and Indic languages) only available as a closed source product.\

Another reason for making this specific add-on closed source is that we don't know of any open source library supporting all of these languages and writing systems. I removed your question asking for alternative open source libraries because you aren't allowed to use Stack Overflow to ask for recommendation for other tools or libraries, but the answer to that question is simple: there are no open source libraries that support HTML to PDF conversion with support for Arabic, Hebrew, Devanagari, Tamil, Telugu, Kannada,... Supporting these languages requires know how that very few developer possess. It would be stupid if we gave away that know how for free (we have to pay salaries too).