# Arabic text is not being displayed in proper format.

Tags: pdf-generation, itext7

We are generating pdf templates from Html text. My template contains combination of Arabic and english words.
Arabic texts are not being displayed correctly in generated pdf. (They should be displayed from right to left).
I have loaded valid pdfcalligraph license key in my code. 
Please let me know if I need to write any code for this; as I searched in web and found that pdf calligraph will automatically detect the Arabic text and do the job.

Comment: You have purchased a license for the iText 7 add-on pdfCalligraph. This includes a support contract. Please contact the vendor (iText Software) for your technical support questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Arabic strings from RTL in PDF generated using itext 7 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621260/how-to-display-arabic-strings-from-rtl-in-pdf-generated-using-itext-7-api)