# Unicode characters rendering issue in signature appearance using iText7

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I am facing an issue with Arabic characters and other non-english characters like spanish characters etc used in signature appearance.
I am creating a custom signature appearance and some values are in Arabic character but the characters are rendered broken. (Image attached)

I am using the following code snippet for adding embedding font:

```
Paragraph appearanceAttributes = new Paragraph();

//Adding other signature appearance attributes

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"D:\\SigningHub\\Code\\Default\\PdfFonts\\arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
appearanceAttributes.SetFont(font);
```

[image]

The actual value of Signed by attribute is: "مرحبا" but it is rendered broken.

Comment: Did you use another font like 'Tahoma'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Arabic strings from RTL in PDF generated using itext 7 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621260/how-to-display-arabic-strings-from-rtl-in-pdf-generated-using-itext-7-api)

Comment: While Arabic certainly requires the calligraphy add-on, Spanish usually should not. You may want to focus on that issue here.

Comment: @mkl
"While Arabic certainly requires the calligraphy add-on"
I could not get this point?
Basically my scenario is to cater non-English characters which includes Norwegian, Polish, Spanish, Arabic etc.

Comment: @usr2564301
I have checked that answer and as far as I understand the solution provided is to add itext.typography dependency in my code to handle this issue. But the downloaded package of iText did not contain this dependency by default.
Right?

Comment: Itext.typography is in the pdfCalligraph itext add-on. It provides support for more complicated ligatures and characters with different forms.

Comment: @mkl
So I need to download this add-on separately as it is not in the itext7 package.
Right?

Comment: For details read [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph). Yes, as that is no universally required dependency, you'll have to explicitly retrieve and add it.

Comment: pdfCalligraph is a commercial add-on, you need to purchase a license to use it. Contact iText sales for a quote. Just FYI.